# output all possible variants of a string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following code which works to print every possible string of lengths 1-4 made up of the characters in `my_list`, but if I were to extend this nested approach to handle output strings of up to length 10, the resulting code would be too long. How can I display all possible variants of length 10?

```
my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

for i in range(len(my_list)):
    print(str(my_list[i]))

for i in range(len(my_list)):
    for o in range(len(my_list)):
        print(str(my_list[i]) + str(my_list[o]))

for i in range(len(my_list)):
    for o in range(len(my_list)):
        for p in range(len(my_list)):
            print(str(my_list[i]) + str(my_list[o]) + str(my_list[p]))

for i in range(len(my_list)):
    for o in range(len(my_list)):
        for p in range(len(my_list)):
            for a in range(len(my_list)):
                print(str(my_list[i]) + str(my_list[o]) + str(my_list[p]) + str(my_list[a]))
```

(sample output)

```
a
b
c
d
aa
ab
ac
ad
ba
bb
bc
bd
[...]
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. Can you please elaborate on "all possible variants of a string"? Please provide an example of: Input --> Expected Output

Comment: maybe you should have a look at [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html)

Comment: "I do not like" is far too vague to be a useful problem statement. Please describe the actual problem you're trying to address.

Comment: [After the OP edited the question to confirm my understanding of the issue, I've cleaned up the text a little to make it more clear.  I suspect this is now a dup of one of the many, many `itertools.product` questions.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you need the `itertools.product` function.

```
import itertools

my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
MAX_LENGTH = 4

for length in range(1,MAX_LENGTH + 1):              
  for x in itertools.product(my_list, repeat=length):
    print(''.join(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `permutations` or `combinations` functions from the **itertools** package. I think that will give you the result you are looking for.

Here is the documentation: https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html

I noticed you added sample output. I think you can achieve this by:

```
from itertools import *
input = "ABCD"
for x in range(1, len(input)+1):
   result = product(input, repeat=x)
   for item in result:
      print "".join(item)
```

Comment: I agree that `itertools` is the right direction, but I don't think `permutations` or `combinations` is what OP is looking for.